Does a Riemannian metric turn the tangent space to a metric space?
Given a Riemannian manifold $(\mathcal M, g)$ and an arbitrary point $p \in \mathcal M$, we know that $g_p (\cdot, \cdot) \equiv \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_p $ defines an inner-product on the tangent space $T_p \mathcal M$. Does this mean that for any pair of tangent vectors $X_p , Y_p \in T_p\mathcal M$, the quantity
$$ \sqrt{\langle X_p - Y_p, X_p - Y_p \rangle_p}  $$
is a distance function on the tangent space?
I think the answer should be yes, as the distance function is naturally induced from the inner product, but I just would like to confirm.

Yes, in fact more is true: the distance function induced by a riemannian metric turns every riemannian manifold into a metric space.

Yes, that's what inner products always do. But the real significance of the Riemannian metric is that it induces a metric on $M$ itself.

Thanks for the replies! I have posted a related question here. It would be great if you could take a look.
